auth_request in nginx: How can the external port be respected when forwarding to an error_page?
I have a server with three docker images (managed by docker compose) running.

A reverse proxy using nginx
An api (PHP+Symfony) that handles authentication, internally using port 80
A Python service that should reuse the authentication from the api container, internally using port 80

The rproxy is the entrypoint to both the api and the python service.
Since there's yet another, unrelated service running on port 80/443 the rproxy is externally accessible at port 800. I don't want to hardcode the port though, there may be another setup where port 80 is available.
My desired control flow when accessing the python service is the following:

Check if user is already authenticated by calling an endpoint within the api container (user/login/state)
If the user is authenticated (response code 200), proxy to the python service
If the user is not yet authenticated (response code 401), redirect the user to the login page within the api container
If the user logs in successfully, redirect back to the originally requested page

My docker compose file looks like this:
services:
  rproxy:
    build: ...
    ports:
      - 800:80
  api:
    build: ...
  secret:
    build: ...

The nginx config looks like this:
server {
  listen 80;

  # Error and access logging
  error_log /dev/stderr debug;
  access_log /dev/stdout combined;

  location /api/ {
      proxy_pass http://api/api/;
      proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }

  location @error401 {
      return 302 $scheme://$host:$server_port/api/user/login/?returnto=$request_uri;
  }

  location /secret/ {
      # Check if user is authenticated by contacting api
      auth_request /api/user/login/state;

      # Redirect to login page on 401 Unauthorized
      error_page 401 403 = @error401;

      # If authenticated, proxy the request as usual
      rewrite ^/secret(/.*)$ $1 break;
      proxy_pass http://secret/;
      proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}

The login state check works as expected. However, the redirect to the login page after a 401 response from the state check does not. I always get redirected to http://server_name:80/api/user/login on port 80 instead of the correct http://server_name:800/api/user/login.
Things I tried:

saving the $server_port variable before triggering the auth_request -> no change in behaviour

location @error401 {
    return 302 $auth_request_host/api/user/login/?returnto=$request_uri;
}
location /secret/ {
    # Check if user is authenticated by contacting api
    auth_request_set $auth_request_host $scheme://$host:$server_port;
    auth_request /api/user/login/state;
}


Hardcoding the port in the error location: Surprisingly this also did not work. At first I get a 302 redirection to the login page on the correct port, followed immediately by another 301 redirect to the non-existing login page on port 80.

location @error401 {
   return 302 $scheme://$host:800/api/user/login/?returnto=$request_uri;
}

Does anyone has an idea how to keep the port in this setup?

Just use return 302 /api/user/login/?returnto=$request_uri; without domain and port.

Of course, within the container, your $server_port is equal to 80. The second redirect is most likely issued by your api app; however, you can try to play with absolute_redirect and port_in_redirect directives.

I find a solution (well, workaround) by making sure the nginx container internal port is always the same as the external port.
This can be achieved using an environment variable and nginx configuration templates (https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/nginx#using-environment-variables-in-nginx-configuration-new-in-119):
docker.compose.yml
services:
  rproxy_portal:
    build: ...
    ports:
      - 800:800
    environment:
      - EXT_PORT=800

default.conf.template (the template part is important)
server {
  listen ${EXT_PORT};
}

Moreover, the configuration file now needs to copied into the templates directory, not to conf.d:
Dockerfile
COPY ./conf/default.conf.template /etc/nginx/templates/

